# How to retrieve multiple select options?

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I have a User that can have multiples Roles.
I created the form using this code:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/add}" th:object="${user}" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="select1">Roles</label> <select
                multiple="multiple" class="form-control"
                id="select1" th:field="*{roles}">
                <option th:each="role : ${roles}" th:field="*{roles}"
                    th:value="${role.id}" th:text="${role.role}">Part name</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

and this is the RequestMapping for it:

```
@GetMapping(value="/add")
    public String addUserForm(Model model) {
        Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
        Role admin = new Role("1","ADMIN");
        Role user = new Role("2","USER");
        roles.add(admin);
        roles.add(user);
        model.addAttribute("user", new User());
        model.addAttribute("roles", roles);
        return "form";

    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveUser(@ModelAttribute User user) {
        userService.save(user);
        return "success";
    }
```

in class User I have

```
@DBRef
private Set<Role> roles; // with getters and setters
```

I always get [null] in roles and other form fields are working, I did not include them for brevity.

Comment: You can only bind to indexed collections (like `List` or an array) not a `Set`. Also the `th:field` expression on the `option` tag shouldn't be there. Finally you will need a `StringToRoleConverter` or property editor to convert from a `String` (what the input from the form is) to an actual `Role`.

Comment: I will try it now, thank you.

Comment: I still get null

Comment: What have you tried/modified... Stating that it isn't working is not really helping.